# Change redirect port of twisted proxy

Tags: python, proxy, twisted

I have a simple proxy server made using twisted

```
destination = portforward.ProxyFactory(dest_host, dest_port)
reactor.listenTCP(listen_port, destination)
reactor.run()
```

I would like to change the dest_port under certain conditions without having to restart the server.

I tried:

```
new_dest = portforward.ProxyFactory(dest_host, new_dest_port)
reactor.listenTCP(listen_port, new_dest)
```

Of course this produced an address already in use exception.

Is this possible to change the proxy destination during operation?

Answer (score 1):

[reactor.listenTCP](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.interfaces.IReactorTCP.html) returns an object which provides [IListeningPort](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.interfaces.IListeningPort.html) which has a `stopListening` method that stops the server on that port (note that it returns a [Deferred](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.defer.Deferred.html) and the server isn't actually stopped until the `Deferred` fires).

You can use this `stopListening` method before your second `listenTCP` call to free up the server port for use by the new, reconfigured server.

Comment: This solution mostly works, all new connections are now sent to the new port.  However established connections continue to send data to the proxy port that has been stopped.  Any idea why that is?  I expected (and wanted) existing connections to be redirected when the port was changed.  Any ideas?

Comment: Doing things with `stopListening` and `listenTCP` only has an effect on the listening port.  The listening port is a distinct thing.  When a connection attempt arrives at the listening port, a new server-side connection object is created to represent it (a transport and a protocol, typically).  The transport and protocol are then entirely separate from the listening port.  Nothing that happens to the port will have an affect on those connections.  If you want the behavior of those connections to change, you'll have to change something on the protocol handling them.